# send data to server using GET method and sim900a

Tags: arduino, sensor, sim900, server

I am trying to send my data to HTTP server using GET method. When i am sending some hardcoded  data manually it is getting stored in database successfully.

```
SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx/api/iot/v1/save-data/10/20/\"");
```

This is working fine and my data is getting stored successfully.

But when i am trying to send real time data i am unable to send it successfully. Let's say

```
float h = DHT.humidity;

float t = DHT.temperature;

SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx/api/iot/v1/save-data/t/h/\"");
```

It is storing the value as t and h instead of their real values.
I tried some different methods also.

```
SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx/api/iot/v1/save-data/tempData=");

SIM900.print(t);

SIM900.print("&humdData=");

SIM900.print(h);

SIM900.print("\"\r\n");
```

But i am getting error.

Can anyone please help me and tell me how should i send my data to make it getting saved successfully.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you split the print into several statements, the first one **should not** be a `println`, it should be just a `print`. If you want, the last print statement could be

```
SIM900.println("\"");
```

In general, when trying to print a single line with embedded data you will use `print()` several times but only use `println()` once, at the end.